# Change float index value to string index value in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas series set like this:

```
1    357
0    212
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

When I used this code:

```
data=data.reindex(index=['A','B'])
```

My result is :

```
A   NaN
B   NaN
Name: target, dtype: float64
```

But I try to achieve this:

```
A    357
B    212
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

So, what mistake did I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_axis` for setting index to a series.

```
data.set_axis(['A','B'],inplace=False)

A    357
B    212
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

As the documentation say :

> If you do reindex a new object is produced unless the new index is 
>   equivalent to the current one. Default values in the new index that do 
>   not have corresponding records in the dataframe are assigned NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
data.index  = ['A','B']
```